# Missing package in OpenSuSE?

Tags: greek

I installed texlive2013. Old functioning LaTeX files complain now for
missing files:

```
No file LGRcmr.fd.! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.
```

Asking pdflatex it answers:

```
For encoding scheme LGR the defaults cmr/m/n do not form a valid font shape
```

Googling, I found the suggestion to load additional packages:
greek-fontenc, greek-inputenc, cbfonts-fd, cbfonts
The third one, cbfonts-fd, is nowhere to be found in OpenSuSE:s texlive distribution. The other packages are not enough: Same error shows up after
installing them. 
Where can I found cbfonts-fd ?

Comment: The missing files are in the package [`babel-greek`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel-greek)

Comment: According to a comment to Herbert you have a special OpenSuSE version. Maybe there is something buggy. In German usenet group `de.comp.text.tex` another user complained about this, too. If you understand German, see this answer (but the most important are the web links): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/de.comp.text.tex/qVFZ6sN8ZJw/hDajtb8-Z4oJ In short: first deinstall, then install dummy-package from CTAN, then full vanilla TeX Live. There two alternatives linked, one of them in German.

Comment: @user44603 the missing file is not in `babel-greek`.

Answer (score 3):

install with SUSEs package manager

```
| texlive-lgreek     | LaTeX macros for using Greek fonts
| texlive-lgreek-doc | Documentation for texlive-lgreek       
| texlive-lgrx       | Greek text with the LGR font encoding       
| texlive-lgrx-doc   | Documentation for texlive-lgrx
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. After loading,  the error persists. LGRcmr.fd is not among those packages. It can be found in cbfonts.fd, but that package does not seem to be available in the OpenSuSE distribution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run `updmap --all` or for MiKTeX update the font setting

Comment: I've done that, but the error is still there. As root, I run mktexlsr; updmap-sys; mktexlsr. Note that there is no option --all. There is a --force, in case you meant that. updmap-sys complains about kanji fonts, but that doesn't matter. On the other hand, running updmap as user gives an error line: updmap: Directory "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" isn't writable:  at /usr/bin/updmap line 1302.

Comment: then it looks like a corrupt NFFS installation. In stall it new.

Comment: Thank you. However, I think that the real problem is that there is no package cbfonts-fd in the OpenSuSE distribution. There exists texlive-cbfonts, but not the accompanying cbfonts-fd, which is the one that provides the missing file. At least, I couldn't find cbfonts-fd in the official repository. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @MNatiello the package [`cbfonts-fd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cbfonts-fd) is on CTAN...

Answer (score 3):

In 12.3 there is a feature of Zypper for this:

use  `zypper install 'tex(<<package filename.extension>>)`

So for you this will be (Withoutput)

```
bash:>zypper install 'tex(lgreek.sty)'

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'tex(lgreek.sty)' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
Resolving package dependencies...

The following NEW packages are going to be installed:
  texlive-lgreek texlive-lgreek-doc 

The following recommended package was automatically selected:
  texlive-lgreek-doc 

2 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 215.0 KiB. After the operation, additional 226.9 KiB will be used.
```

[Source,](http://jaegerandi.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/easy-way-to-install-tex-packages-for.html) (I was stuck and worked this out just now)